# How to retrieve json data in jquery. asp.net webService C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, web-services

I'm just creating a simple script that manipulates **JSON** data by using **jquery** `$.post()`.

So far this is what I had:

**DateWebService.asmx**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for DateWebService
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class DateWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string GetDateTime()
        {
            return DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }  
    }
}
```

**Default.aspx**

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "DateWebService.asmx/GetDateTime",
     data: "{}",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (msg)
       {
           alert(msg.d);
       }
 });
```

The code above is working. But what I want to do is instead of using `$.ajax()` I want to use `$.post();` something like this:

```
 $.post("DateWebService.asmx/GetDateTime", {}, function(data){
     alert(data.d);
 }, "json")
 .fail(function(){ alert("error"); });
```

But what I get is an error message.

Comment: what is your error message?

Comment: i got an alert message came from here .fail(function(){ alert("error"); });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this, it may helpful to you

```
 $.post("DateWebService.asmx/GetDateTime", {}, function(data){
 if (data.success) {
 alert(data.d);
 }
 else
 {
     //show some error message
 }
 }, "json")
```

Comment: tnx for your quick response but base on your code i got an alert message of "error again"

Comment: public string GetDateTime()
        {
            return DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        }

Comment: did you test it?
$.post("DateWebService.asmx/GetDateTime", {}, function(data){
 if (data.success) {
 alert(data.d);
 }
 else
 {
     alert("error 1")
 }
 }, "json").fail(function(){ alert("error again"); });

the only line that executed is the fail function so i always get an error of "error again"

Comment: @user2932692 is it necessary to use fail function. any way we are checking success and fail. i think it is not necessary to use again